# Jekyll CSS not appearing on Github.io

Tags: html, css, github, jekyll

I don't understand what's wrong with my code. I can host my website on a local server using Jekyll. However, when i try to create a github.io page i am getting the following error:

The page build failed with the following error:

A file was included in `portfolio/index.html` that is a symlink or does not exist in your `_includes` directory. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-file-is-a-symlink.

Also, when I try to link my CSS with HTML on the Github page it doesn't work as well. Here is the index.html i am working with. The index.html is in a folder called portfolio, and inside another folder named "_inlcudes" is where about.html is

```
---
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/input.css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="functions.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div>
{% include header.html %}
</div>

<div>
{%include about.html %}
</div>

<div>
{%include technology.html %}
</div>

<div>
{% include footer.html %}
</div>

<div>
{% include technical-projects.html %}}
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "Settings" page for your GitHub repo, make sure you select the theme you want to use.